# lead and lag times

Tags: planning, tools, gantt

in the Project Management framework I am developing http://www.lowcoupling.com I have defined a Domain Specific Language enabling a declarative description of schedules and plans. Like

```
   Project project1 {

        Activity activity1 {
        starts '31/08/2013' ;
        ends '20/9/2013';
        completeness 20 % ;
        }

       /*
        * activity2 description
       */
       Activity activity2 {
        after project1.activity1 offset 1;
        duration 30;
        completeness 0%;
        dependsOn project1.activity1;
       }
  }
```

As you can see you can define the starting date of an activity, its end date or its duration.

[image]

Alternatively you can express you want an activity to start after (the end of) another with an offset (in days). As you can see the keyword to that is 'offset' and it can be either positive or negative (days before the end of the related activity).

My question is: Do you think it would be more appropriate (and maybe elegant) to use the keywords '**lead**' and '**lag**' instead of '**offset**'?

Answer (score 1):

My two cents: It is clearest if you use "Offset".